# Approximating $\tau(x)$ from $x=|\tau(x)|^{1/\beta-1}(\beta-1)^{1/\beta}\frac{\pi/\beta}{\sin(\pi/\beta)}-|\tau(x)|^{-1}+o(|\tau(x)|^{-1})$

Tags: calculus, approximation, large-deviation-theory, birth-death-process

I have come upon the equation
$$x=|\tau(x)|^{1/\beta-1}(\beta-1)^{1/\beta}\frac{\pi/\beta}{\sin(\pi/\beta)}-|\tau(x)|^{-1}+o(|\tau(x)|^{-1})$$
and the author of the paper states, that it leads to the approximation
$$\tau(x)\sim -b(\beta)x^{-\beta/(\beta-1)}, \quad b(\beta):=(\beta-1)^{1/(\beta-1)}\left(\frac{\pi/\beta}{\sin(\pi/\beta)}\right)^{\beta/(\beta-1)} \text{for } x\rightarrow0.$$
For the function $\tau(x)$ holds $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}=-\infty, \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}=(\beta-1)^{-1}$, $\tau(1)=0$, and it is strongly increasing.

So far, I have made not alot of progress in comprehending this, and I am wondering, if anybody could help me?

Greetings, Prob

Comment: Could you give a link to the paper ?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08794 at the top of page 13

Comment: yeah sorry, thought i had included that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can re-arrange the initial equation into
$$\tag{1}
1 + x\left| {\tau (x)} \right| + o(1) = \left| {\tau (x)} \right|^{1/\beta } (\beta  - 1)^{1/\beta } \frac{{\pi /\beta }}{{\sin (\pi /\beta )}}.
$$
Taking the power of $\beta/(\beta-1)$ of both sides gives
$$
(1 + x\left| {\tau (x)} \right| + o(1))^{\beta /(\beta  - 1)}   = \left| {\tau (x)} \right|^{1/(\beta  - 1)} b(\beta )
$$
which, after further simplification, becomes
$$
\left( {\frac{1}{{x\left| {\tau (x)} \right|}} + 1 + o\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x\left| {\tau (x)} \right|}}} \right)} \right)^{\beta /(\beta  - 1)}  = \left| {\tau (x)} \right|^{ - 1} b(\beta )x^{ - \beta /(\beta  - 1)} .
$$
Now since $x|\tau(x)|\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ (this follows from $|\tau(x)|\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$ and $(1)$), we obtain
$$
\left| {\tau (x)} \right|^{ - 1} b(\beta )x^{ - \beta /(\beta  - 1)}  \to 1
$$
as $x\to 0$. Since $\tau(x) \to -\infty$ as $x\to 0$, we must have
$$
 - (\tau (x))^{ - 1} b(\beta )x^{ - \beta /(\beta  - 1)}  \to 1
$$
as $x\to 0$.

Comment: Very nice manipulation !

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helped me out!