# Solving $x=|\tau(x)|^{1/\beta-1}(\beta-1)^{1/\beta}\frac{\pi/\beta}{\sin(\pi/\beta)}-|\tau(x)|^{-1}+o(|\tau(x)|^{-1})$ for $\tau(x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

How do you solve the following equation for $\tau(x)$?
\begin{equation}
x=|\tau(x)|^{1/\beta-1}(\beta-1)^{1/\beta}\frac{\pi/\beta}{\sin(\pi/\beta)}-|\tau(x)|^{-1}+o(|\tau(x)|^{-1})
\end{equation}
The author of the paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.08794.pdf, page 13) states that
\begin{equation}
\tau(x)=x^{-1}-b(\beta)x^{-\beta/(\beta-1)}+o(x^{-1}),\quad b(\beta):=(\beta-1)^{1/(\beta-1)}\left(\frac{\pi/\beta}{\sin(\pi/\beta)}\right)^{\beta/(\beta-1)}
\end{equation}
is the solution, but I wonder how to get there.
For the function $\tau(x)$ holds $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}=-\infty, \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}=(\beta-1)^{-1}$ and $\tau(1)=0$, $\beta>1$.
Another user has helped me to understand that
\begin{equation}
\tau(x)\sim -b(\beta)x^{-\beta/(\beta-1)} \text{ for } x\rightarrow0.
\end{equation}
([Approximating $\tau(x)$ from $x=|\tau(x)|^{1/\beta-1}(\beta-1)^{1/\beta}\frac{\pi/\beta}{\sin(\pi/\beta)}-|\tau(x)|^{-1}+o(|\tau(x)|^{-1})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175389/approximating-taux-from-x-taux1-beta-1-beta-11-beta-frac-p)), but I'm not sure if that helps/how to apply that for this problem.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The coefficient at $x^{-1}$ is not correct though. Suppose we have the equation $x = (\tau/b)^{-1/p} - \tau^{-1}$ with $p > 1$ and we're looking for the solution which tends to infinity when $x$ tends to zero. The first term comes from solving $x = (\tau/b)^{-1/p}$. To find the next term, we take $\tau = b x^{-p} (1 + \epsilon)$ and apply the method of dominant balance again, which gives $x^p/b = -x \epsilon/p$. We obtain
$$\tau = b x^{-p} - p x^{-1} + o(x^{-1}).$$

Comment: @Maxim I am still trying to figure out how you came to this, how do you apply the method of dominant balance again?

Comment: Substitute $\tau = b x^{-p} (1 + \epsilon)$ into the equation and expand $(1 + \epsilon)^a$ into series in $\epsilon$. Then (after cancelling two identical terms coming from the first step) discard all the terms which are a small o of some other term when $x \to 0$ and $\epsilon \to 0$. There will be two terms left, which have to be equal.